# Java connection to database not working

Tags: java, connection, database-connection

I need help with this code for establishing a connection to a database.

```
try
{
String str="SELECT * FROM Author WHERE city LIKE 'P%'";
 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con =
DriverManager.getConnection     
("jdbc:odbc:myds;databaseName=Library;user=sa;password=password123");
Statement  =con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs= executeQuery();
System.out.println("Author ID\tAuthor Name\tCity");
while (rs.next())
{
String id=rs.getString("au_id");
String name=rs.getString("au_name");
String city=rs.getString("city");
System.out.print(id+"\t");
if (name.length() <=7)
System.out.print(name+"\t\t");
else
System.out.print("\t"+name+"\t");
System.out.println(city);
}
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
System.out.println("Error occurred");
System.out.println("Error:"+ex);
```

What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: PLEASE AVOID SHOUTING. Plus, it's much easier to read text that uses upper and lower cases appropriately. Your help in this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error message/exception/etc.. ?

Comment: Um, so any error messages? What is it not doing that it should be?

Comment: Why don't you tell is what's wrong?  Does it compile? Does it throw Run-time errors?

Comment: If this is your **real** code - you're missing curly brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I think it sould be something like that

```
String str="SELECT * FROM Author WHERE city LIKE 'P%'";
// Some stuff 
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); //stmt added
// Some more stuff 
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(str); // stmt and str added
```

You should take a look at [Execute SQL Queries with Java Application.](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/execute-sql-query.shtml)